# Continuity and Uniform Continuity for functions of one variable (topological definitions)in analysis course

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

Hello i need to know what is the exact meaning of this expression:
Continuity and Uniform Continuity for functions of one variable (topological definitions) in  analysis course.
Does it mean the usual definition:

If $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function and $a\in D$ then we say that 
f is continuous at a if:
$(\forall \epsilon>0) (\exists \delta>0) (\forall x\in D) , |x-a|< \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Or it's the same definition but using metric distances instead of absolute values.

Comment: See e.g. [Continuous function : Definition in terms of neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_neighborhoods).

Comment: Hello @MauroALLEGRANZA. Is this definition suitable for an analysis course?

Comment: See e.g William Ziemer, [Modern real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=WCpBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36), Springer (2nd ed 2017), page 36.

Comment: It there a similar definition for uniform continuity using neighborhood?

Answer (score 0):

You should use distance on the left and absolute value on the right, that is,$$d(x,a)<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(a)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: If D\subset \mathbb{R}, then this distance at left would be the absolute value?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of continuity at a point is

If $$f:D→R$$ is a function and $a∈D$ then we say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if: $$(∀ϵ>0)(∃δ>0)(∀x∈D),d(x,y)<δ \implies |f(x)−f(a)|<\epsilon .$$

A function is continuous on $D$ if it is continuous at every point $x\in D$

On the other hand the uniform continuity is defined as

If $$f:D→R$$ is a function, then we say that $f$ is  uniformly continuous on $D$

if: $$(∀ϵ>0)(∃δ>0)(∀x , y ∈D),d(x,y)<δ\implies |f(x)−f(y)|<\epsilon .$$

Comment: Hello, are these definitions considered as topological definitions?

Comment: Yes, in standard topology of real line these are topological definitions. If you use a different metric then the absolute values change to d(x,y).

Comment: @RabihAssaf they are  the standard "metric definitions", we could replace the open balls in the  domain by relatively open neighbourhoods, if you prefer. Uniform continuity needs a metric (or really, a uniformity) on the domain. There is no purely topological alternative, of course.